# Need help removing specific file extension from a folder

Tags: python, file, duplicates

I am currently writing a python code to access each directory and delete the specific type of file extension specified. However, I only want the code to delete the files if there are two files with same name but different file extensions are present.

ie. I only want mytext.txt to delete if mytext.txt and mytext.docx are present both in the same folder, if only mytext.txt is present then I want the code to skip that specific folder.

I have added the following lines to remove the files with extension no matter the condition:

```
for item in test:
    if item.endswith('.txt'):
        os.remove(os.path.join(pathforRemove, item))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `'f1.txt', 'f2.png', 'f2.txt', 'f3.png', 'f4.txt'`
are your files:

```
from collections import defaultdict
test = ['f1.txt', 'f2.png', 'f2.txt', 'f3.png', 'f4.txt']

# construct a filename to extensions map
fname_to_ext = defaultdict(set)
pairs = list(map(lambda s: (s[:s.rfind('.')], s[s.rfind('.'):]), test))
for fname, ext in pairs:
    fname_to_ext[fname].add(ext)

for fname, exts in fname_to_ext.items():
    if len(exts) > 1 and '.txt' in exts:
        print('deleting: ', fname + '.txt')
        # os.remove(os.path.join(pathforRemove, item))
```

This prints:

```
deleting:  f2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly modify your answer to check if this condition exists by storing it in a `dict` with each value as a `list`. Then we gather all the values from the dictionary who have a length greater than two and have files that end in `'.txt'`. Once we have all those values we delete them.

```
from collections import defaultdict

recs = defaultdict(list)

for item in test:
    name = os.path.basename(item)
    no_ext = name.split('.')[0]
    recs[no_ext].append(name)

to_delete = [val for v in recs.values() for val in v if len(v) >= 2 and val.endswith('.txt')]

for item in to_delete:
    os.remove(os.path.join(pathforRemove, item))
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this code snippet to see if fulfill your ask:

```
import os
rootDir = '/test-dir-traverse'
extensionToBeRetained = 'docx'
extensionToBeRemoved = 'txt'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fnameToBeRemoved in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fnameToBeRemoved)
        for fname in fileList:
            if fnameToBeRemoved.endswith(extensionToBeRemoved) and fname.endswith(extensionToBeRetained) and fnameToBeRemoved[0:-len(extensionToBeRemoved)] == fname[0:-len(extensionToBeRetained)]:
                print('Deleting file : {}').format(fnameToBeRemoved)
```

You can adjust file extensions and change further.